# Is the GNOME Shell source code the code to the GNOME DE?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

When browsing the internet, I found that there were two repositories that looked like source code to GNOME DE. One was called GNOME Utility Library and the other was called GNOME Shell. Which would I download in order to modify the source code to the whole GNOME DE? Even better, can someone explain the difference between the two projects? I'm new to Linux.

Also, I do understand that me being new to Linux will make it challenging to modify the GNOME DE. Although, I do have prior experience with coding. In other words, please don't answer my question with something like, "Editing the source code of the GNOME DE would be very challenging and not suitable for someone like you. I would recommend doing some more digging first.", because I am currently digging into the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNOME Shell is one component of the GNOME desktop environment; there are many other components, and you’ll find their source code in repositories hosted on [GNOME’s GitLab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME).

GNOME Shell handles the desktop, window switching (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>), the application overview, etc. See [the GNOME Shell Tour](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Tour) for details.

To find out which component you need to modify in order to achieve something you want to do, you’re probably better off looking through [the list of projects](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects) and [applications](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps) rather than trying to find the right repository by exploring the repositories. GNOME also has a good [newcomers’ guide](https://wiki.gnome.org/Newcomers/) which can help you get started.